# Sanitization, disinfection, sterilization of Dishwasher?

Tags: equipment, maintenance

How to do more then just clean of dishwasher ? I mean: how to sanitize or even disinfect or sterilize ?

`"Many people are misinformed about the difference between clean, sanitized, disinfected, and sterilized."` - [quote from ANFP](http://www.anfponline.org/CE/food_protection/2011_03.shtml)

In place I currently rent there is Electrolux GA55LV220 Dishwasher and I am completely puzzled which methods are both: safe for dishwasher (it's not mine, rented...) and will clean bacteria&friends safely to our health after previous unknown users.

I allowed myselfe to post here, as maintenance category of this site feels like good fit, because regular sanitization of dishwasher (e.g. every 1-3 months) is recommended in couple of places like good idea.

*So far reseach:
For example, I see [in this](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/disinfect-dishwasher-20635.html) and other articles, advice to use chlorine bleach, because of [it's disinfection properties](https://www.olinbleach.com/the-power-of-bleach/are-chlorine-and-bleach-the-same-thing/). However there is always warining to "not use it for dishwasher with a stainless steel interior" as it will erode metal. I tried to find if that applies to Electrolux GA55LV220, but the only note I found in [user's manual](http://www.elektroshop24.ch/electrolux/geschirrspueler/ga55lv220_electrolux_geschirrspueler_montageanleitung.pdf) on page 58, is "There can be water on the sides and on the door of the appliance. Stainless steel becomes cool more quickly then the dishes", so I am not sure if they meant it's stainless steel (IMHO it should be verbatim on other pages, like technical specs) of if they copied this part from other manuals.*

*Also we've bought "Javel Wasser Plus" substance for desinfection with following description of ingredients: "Inhaltsstoffe: unter 5% Bleichmittel auf Chlorbasis (Natriumhypochlorit)
"(according to Google Translate : Ingredients: less than 5% chlorine-based bleach (sodium hypochlorite)". So it looks to me like recommended in [previously mentioned](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/disinfect-dishwasher-20635.html) articles, but still I am not sure if it will not erode dishwasher and if there are other good alternatives.*

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of bleach harming stainless steel in any way. However, you may want to clean it with bleach and then run the cycle with nothing or with white vinegar afterward to rinse the bleach off. I would not run the dry cycle after either of these cycles, of course.

Comment: Thank you @Anne for answer. I've found during search that there.are.different kinds of bleaches and best for sanitization seems to be chlorine one while also with potential of letting steel to erode. I believe you've meant your knowledge/experience about chlorine bleach. Let me double chceck - maybe other respondents can confirm or deny concerns.